# Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

Tags: drivers, usb, permissions

I am trying to connect to my PC (Kubuntu 21.10 - kernel: 5.13.0-40)
a Baofeng UV-5r transponder using Chirp SW with a USB-serial cable:
`Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter`

but I receive the following error message:

```
[Errno 13] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0:[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
```

I have checked the CH340 device driver and it is seems to be loaded in the kernel:

```
ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M  
ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
|__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, **Driver=ch341**, 12M  
ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter
```

Here is the list of ttyUSB dev files (/dev)

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 1 apr 26 16:08 ttyUSB1  
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 2 apr 26 16:08 ttyUSB2  
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 3 apr 26 16:26 ttyUSB3
```

(*user* belongs to *dialout* group)

Comment: Have you tried adding your user to the dialout group ?

Comment: Did you logout/login after adding yourself to the `dialout` group? Check with `id`. Groups are set up in the login process.

Comment: My user (fabrizio) is already in dialout group:

Comment: I have similar problem and even manually change permissions to 666 (with visual confirmation, I still get permission problem (user in dialout group, dialout group exits, device loaded in kernel.) @FabrizioCapobianco, you still have problem even if manually changing permission?

Answer (score 3):

Just a hint that might be the cause of the problem (worth a shot). Change your device permissions by:

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

**WARNING**: This solution is only for testing purposes! For production usages you should dig deeper to this command and only active the options that is actually needed! (i.e. **not** giving every single user the ability to read, write and execute from your `/dev/ttyUSB0`)

Comment: This *finally* solved my Chirp problem on Debian 12 :)